# Pulumi - Azure - Typescript issue with writing a function

Tags: typescript, azure, pulumi

I don't have experience with Pulumi/typescript, before I used terraform at my previous jobs.

I have two files, index.ts and blob.ts please see below.

I have create function which is creating storage account,resource group, blob container, and needs to send on the monitor, key for storage account.

I am having issue with last part of blob.ts file

export const storageAccountKeys = pulumi.all([resourceGroup.name,

if there is export, I am having error, if is not export there, script is working, but not writing me key for storage account.

**Error says : Modifiers cannot appear here.ts(1184)**

Idea is to have only functions in index.ts, and all other code to be in other *.ts files.

Where is my mistake, what is wrong ? is there any other way how to write on monitor storage account key ?

```
//     blob.ts       //

import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as resources from "@pulumi/azure-native/resources";
import * as storage from "@pulumi/azure-native/storage";


export default function CreateStorageContainer() {


// Create an Azure Resource Group

const resourceGroup = new resources.ResourceGroup("somegroup", {
    location: "westeurope",
    resourceGroupName: "somegroup",
});


// Create an Azure resource (Storage Account)
const storageAccount = new storage.StorageAccount("sgsomestorageaccount", {
    accountName: "sgsomestorageaccount",
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    sku: {
        name: storage.SkuName.Standard_LRS,
    },
    kind: storage.Kind.StorageV2,
});

// Create Blob container with name : 
const blobContainer = new storage.BlobContainer("someblobcontainer", {
    accountName: storageAccount.name,
    containerName: "someblobcontainer",
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
});


// Export the primary key of the Storage Account
export const storageAccountKeys = pulumi.all([resourceGroup.name, storageAccount.name]).apply(([resourceGroupName, accountName]) =>
    storage.listStorageAccountKeys({ resourceGroupName, accountName }));
const primaryStorageKey = storageAccountKeys.keys[0].value;

}
```

```
   //  index.ts //

import CreateStorageContainer from "./blob.ts"

CreateStorageContainer();
```

[Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqDfb.png)

[Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVO8j.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't export a value from a function, you need to return something.

```js
//     blob.ts       //

import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as resources from "@pulumi/azure-native/resources";
import * as storage from "@pulumi/azure-native/storage";
import { ProximityPlacementGroupType } from "@pulumi/azure-native/compute/v20191201";

export default function CreateStorageContainer() {
  // Create an Azure Resource Group

  const resourceGroup = new resources.ResourceGroup("somegroup", {
    location: "westeurope",
    resourceGroupName: "somegroup",
  });

  // Create an Azure resource (Storage Account)
  const storageAccount = new storage.StorageAccount("sgsomestorageaccount", {
    accountName: "sgsomestorageaccount",
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    sku: {
      name: storage.SkuName.Standard_LRS,
    },
    kind: storage.Kind.StorageV2,
  });

  // Create Blob container with name :
  const blobContainer = new storage.BlobContainer("someblobcontainer", {
    accountName: storageAccount.name,
    containerName: "someblobcontainer",
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
  });

  // Export the primary key of the Storage Account
  const storageAccountKeys = pulumi
    .all([resourceGroup.name, storageAccount.name])
    .apply(([resourceGroupName, accountName]) =>
      storage.listStorageAccountKeys({ resourceGroupName, accountName })
    );
  const primaryStorageKey = storageAccountKeys.keys[0].value;

  return [ storageAccountKeys, primaryStorageKey ] // return whatever you need here

}
```

If you then want to export those values from Pulumi, you'll need to do that in your `index.ts`

```js
import CreateStorageContainer from "./blob"

export const foo = CreateStorageContainer();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Jaxxstorm, on the end, I realised I don't need to export anything, as this will be run in pipeline.